# Repetir una misma estructura XAML varias veces

Tags: c#, xaml

Tengo esta estructura...

```
    <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Margin="4" Content="Potencia  4 Polos"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="0" Background="#eee"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="0" Background="#eee"/>
               </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

¿Puedo de alguna manera repetir el codigo varias veces uno encima del otro sin repetirlo? Creando una plantilla o alguna manera similar

Answer (score 1):

Crea un control y agregale el codigo. Entonces cuando quieres reutilizarlo, solo tienes que importar tu control utilizando el atributo `xmlns`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SO_app.ForAsperger"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VM;assembly=VM"//this is where we define reference to our ViewModel
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Model;assembly=Model"//this is where we define our model object so we know the structure for our DataTemplate
         mc:Ignorable="d" 

         xmlns:miControl="namespace.deTu.Control">

         <miControl:NombreDelControl></miControl:NombreDelControl>

</UserControl>
```

`xmlns:miControl=""` es donde debes de incluir el namespace donde esta localizado tu control.